# Action Link in CodeBehind, irrespective of current Request Context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Trying to write a helper method to generate `actionlink` in code Behind.

```
public static String CodeBehindActionLink(UrlHelper url, String actionloction,string actiontext)
        {
            var linkBuilder = new TagBuilder("a");

            linkBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", url.Action(actionloction)); //url is culprit here

            linkBuilder.SetInnerText(actiontext);

            return linkBuilder.ToString();
        }
```

**Callee**

```
CodeBehindActionLink(new  
 UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext), 
Url.Action("A", "B", new { area = "C"}),"SomeName");
```

the Expected out is like  `<a href="C/B/A">SomeName</a>`

but current context is appending unnecessary route in anchor. if its in same context then the anchor tag is look like `<a href="C/B/C/B/A" >SomeName</a>`.

how can we override this behavior.

**found solution** : *no need of passing request context. pass only `actionlocation`*.

```
linkBuilder.MergeAttribute("href", actionloction);
```

and callee look like

```
CodeBehindActionLink(
        Url.Action("A", "B", new { area = "C"}),"SomeName");
```

cause `Url.Action` already take care of exact `route`.

Comment: @JitendraPancholi  The `Request` Context.

Comment: Why are you creating this helper method? Url.Action is doing the same job for you. Any specific reason? And you already provided your solution in the question.

Comment: i need anchor HTML snippet in `codebehind` to pass on view. which Url.Action wont gives.